# Creating new xlm macros in excel 2007

Tags: excel, macros, xlm, excel-4.0

Is it still possible to create (note **create**: not run) xlm macros in Excel 2007? I have an interest in historical languages (yes, I know xlm macros aren't going that far back in the grand scheme of things) and want to muck around with them.

I've searched the web and there's a million hits for how to enable support for legacy xlm macros, and that's all well and good. But I'm looking for info on how to create new ones. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a macro sheet in XL2007 - Right-click a sheet tab, choose Insert and then Excel 4 Macro sheet.

Answer (score 2):

It may or may not need a macro sheet. But the actual question was how to create the macro itself. It must be declared as a macro. In XL 14, which still supports XL4 macros (Excel macros, as opposed to VBA macros (Visual Basic macros)), you write a series of XLM commands in a column. It will be executed top down. To declare it, you select the top cell of that range, then under the 'insert' menu, under the 'name' submenu, pick 'define'. Give it a suitable name and hit 'add'. Then select it within the same dialog, and radio buttons will appear below. They will offer 'command', 'function', or 'none'. Choose command or function, as appropriate.